# Anaconda Python On Chromebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I recently installed Anaconda python on my chromebook to utilize python adn test some of my scripts out, but I'm a little stumped of how can I download libraries and import them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you are in the anaconda environment you can use `pip install <library>` to install libraries, you can search for them with `pip search <library>`. When they are installed with pip you can `import <library>` them like usual.